# How do I update my database with the content of a TextBox?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a database table with three columns: `User`, `Pass`, `Money`. I also have a vb form with a button and a `TextBox` named `Money`. What's the query code for updating the `Money` in the database, so it would be the same as the `TextBox` in the form?

Answer (score 1):

Check [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728894%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) , You are probably looking for it .

an update query can be

```
UPDATE Categories 
SET Money = @MoneyTextBox WHERE (user =   @currentUser)
```

Answer (score 1):

With this piece of code you should be able to connect and update an Access database

```
Dim Connection As New OledbConnection("Provider=microsoft.Jet.oledb.4.0;DataSource=YourDatabase.mdb;") 

        Try               
            Connection.Open()

            Dim Query = "UPDATE TableName SET Money = ? WHERE User = ?"
            Dim command As New OleDbCommand
            With command
                .CommandText = Query
                .Connection = Connection
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", MoneyTextBox.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", UserTextBox.Text)
            End With

            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch exception As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message)
        Finally
            Connection.Close()
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

use Update Query

```
"update Databasename set Money='"& MoneyTextBox.Text &"' where user='" & UserTextBox.Text &"' and Pass='"PassTextBox.Text"' "
```

Comment: Also that's not the best way to update a database. Using parameterized query you'll avoid SQL Injection attacks. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work